# Importar clases de módulo a módulo de python en vsCode?

Tags: python, vscode, python-import

tengo un pequeño problema para importar clases de un módulo a otro de python en vscode, lo he hecho de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven me marca un error, aunque el programa funciona. Entonces probé de manera que la sintaxis *sea correcta*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que es correcta, pero el programa no funciona

Módulo de Prueba:

```
class Persona:

def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, edad):
   
    self._nombre = nombre 
    self._apellido = apellido
    self._edad = edad

#Método get

@property
def nombre(self):
    return self._nombre

#Método set
@nombre.setter
def nombre(self, nombre):
    self._nombre = nombre

@property
def apellido(self):
    return self._apellido

@apellido.setter
def apellido(self, apellido):
    self._apellido = apellido

@property
def edad(self):
    return self._edad

@edad.setter
def edad(self, edad):
    self._edad = edad

def mostrarDetalle(self):
    print(f'Persona: {self._nombre} {self._apellido} {self._edad}')
```

Módulo de PruebaPersona:

```
from .Prueba import Persona
persona1 = Persona('Karla', 'Gomez', 30)
print(persona1.mostrarDetalle())
```

Comment: como estan estructurados tus directorio?, que contiene cada archivo?, por favor complementa tu pregunta.

Comment: Te puedo decir que la primera forma esta bien y que tu IDE esta mal, pero nada es seguro si no das mas detalles.

Comment: Claro, los dos archivos que utilizo están en una carpeta en mi escritorio

Comment: Si, también pienso que el problema es del IDE, pero no he logrado encontrar la forma de solucionarlo

Comment: Lo siento, ya lo subí como texto

Comment: si lo intentas de la primera forma te funciona (ignorando el error de vscode)???

Comment: Gracias, ya descubrí el error, resulta que lo módulos tienen que estar en la carpeta general y no en subcarpetas

Comment: La primer forma esta bien solo que su editor no lo reconoce, debe ser el Linting.
Para la segunda forma requeriría un archivo __init__.py para poder usar ese . (punto) de importaciones relativas